# How do I get my google spreadsheet to open to today's date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is a link to my document:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wBpeCUTmePD3N5CDz57LeBBWZHnSwrX-5b6XscdbB4s/edit?usp=sharing

I want the document to open to today's date or to the Monday of each week.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000;
  var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);
  var ssdate; 
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) { 
    try { 
      ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day; 
    } catch(e) { } 
    if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) { 
      sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to write an [`onOpen()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onopen) trigger using Google Apps Script.

Comment: i have tried that from other peoples questions and answers but does now work for some reason

Comment: You've tried what? Show your code.

Comment: function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");
 var values = range.getValues();  
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your attempt is that you grabbed *column* A, but your dates exist in *row* 2. Try this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("2018"); // Specifiy the sheet
  var range = sheet.getRange("2:2"); // Row 2
  var values = range.getValues()[0]; // This is a 2-dimensional array in the form [[row1-col1, row1-col2],[row2-col1,row2-col2]].
  // Because we only pulled one row (Row 2), we can immediately select just that row by appending the [0]

  var today = new Date();
  var todayDate = today.getDate();
  var todayMonth = today.getMonth();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();

  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) { 
    var columnDate = new Date(values[i]);
    if (columnDate.getDate() === todayDate && columnDate.getMonth() === todayMonth && columnDate.getFullYear() === todayYear) {
      sheet.getRange(1, i+1).activate();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Once i have added this to script editor how do i apply this to the sheet?

Comment: Copy/paste the code, save, run the function, accept the permissions. Then you simply open the spreadsheet. (You have to re-open it if already open.)