# how do I open my sheet automatically on next week's date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have used a code found in another post (thank you very much, see below), to make a sheet open on Today's date.

Please, could you advise where I would need to add "+7" (or something else) to make it open on the date a week from now (Today + 7 days)?

[How do I get my google spreadsheet to open to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49787361/how-do-i-get-my-google-spreadsheet-to-open-to-todays-date)

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("1:1");

 var values = range.getValues(); 
 values = values[0];
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 Logger.log(today);
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(0,i,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }

}
```

Comment: If today means date like "November 21", maybe you can just do var todayAfter7 = today + 7, and then check, if today == todayAfter7 then LogIn

Comment: i just figured it out by trial and error.... in case it helps anyone out:  if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today+7) {

Comment: thanks for your help Mouvre,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onOpen() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet=ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range=sheet.getRange("1:1");
 var values=range.getValues()[0]; 
 var today=new Date();
 var nextweek=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+7); 
 for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
   var ssdate = values[i].getTime()/86400000;   
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == nextweek) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(0,i,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }
}
```